# input:invalid css rule is applied on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

Check out these two fiddles in Firefox or Chrome.
In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hezgkxoh/2/) one, I've got just a simple form with a `required` attribute and a `submit` button.  Pressing "submit" when the box is empty causes it to be styled as `invalid` (in Firefox, it's a red outline).  But it waits until you press submit to show that it's invalid.

Now try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/16fuhf6r/) one.  It's identical, except that there's some css:

```
input:invalid{
    border-color:orange
}
```

Except this time the orange border color is applied even **before** submit is pressed.  So if and only if you manually set an `invalid` style for a form, the browser applies it before, which is not intuitive behavior.  Of course a required field will invalid before you enter anything.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: According to the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid#HTML_Content) for the `:invalid` pseudo class, it appears that it is working like the spec outlines it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/CaseyRule/16fuhf6r/2/

Style it like this:

```
form.submitted input:invalid{
    border-color:orange
}
```

And then add this JavaScript (I'm using jQuery here):

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click( function(){
    $('form').addClass('submitted');
});
```

I don't believe there is a way to achieve this yet without JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

There is a good article [HERE](https://matemarschalko.medium.com/advanced-css-only-input-fields-interactive-animated-validated-d7ecff3cde8c#c828) about how to prevent :invalid styles from activating on page load (as well as other css tricks). The technique requires a Placeholder attribute, but other than that, it's a pure css solution.

```
input:not(:placeholder-shown):not(:focus):invalid {
    border-color:orange;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox you can use:

```
:-moz-ui-invalid:not(output)
```

This the pseudo class added by the browser to give the red glow. It's not added at page load or all the inputs would have this glow. I've not found the equivalent in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It's been ages but I couldn't find any solution in my quick search that didn't required JS or something overcomplicated. But it's as simple as using this instead:

```
input:user-invalid {
 border-color:orange;
}
```

PS: For anyone in the future needing this. It's never too late to help anyone.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe this works:

```
input:invalid{
    border-color:orange !important;
}
```

This will overwrite any other border colours assigned to the input when it's invalid.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the OP's question. The question is why the CSS is applied ***before*** the form is submitted versus after the form is submitted. In this case there's not a precedence issue. The CSS loads correctly.