# HTML Validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to validate every input in my HTML Form. But at the same time, I want to make the textbox borders appear red, when a user didn't input anything or didn't meet the format, requirement input in my form. Any tips on how to do `

```
     <body background='bgimg.jpg'>
     <form id='forma'align='center'>
        <fieldset class='fieldset-auto-width'>


        <div>
            <label for='fname'><b>FirstName:</b></label>
            <input type='text' value='' name='fname' placeholder='Enter First Name' required='required' pattern='[a-z]'/>
            </div>

        <div>
            <label for='lname'><b>LastName:</b></label>
            <input type='text' value='' name='lname'placeholder='Enter Last Name' required='required'/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for='pass'><b>Password:</b></label>
            <input type='password' value'' name='pass' placeholder='Enter Password' required='required'/>
        </div>  

        <div>
            <label for='eAdd'><b>Email Address:</b></label>
            <input type='text' value='' name='eAdd' placeholder='e.g: ilovehtml@html.com' required='required'/> 
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for='hAdd'><b>Home Address:</b></label>
            <input type='text' value='' name='hAdd' size:'30' placeholder='Enter Current Home Address' required='required'/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for='gender'><b>Gender:</b></label>
            <input type='radio' value='Male' name='gender' required='required' />Male
            <input type='radio' value='Female' name='gender'/> Female
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for='status'><b>Status:</b></label>
            <input type='radio' value='Single' name='status' required='required'/> Single
            <input type='radio' value='Married' name='status'/> Married 
            <input type='radio' value='Widow' name='status'/> Widow
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for='dob'><b>Date of Birth:</b></label>
            <input type='date' value='' name='dob'placeholder='MM/DD/YY' required='required'/> 
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for='bansa'><b>Country:</b></label>
            <select  name='country' >
                <option value='AR'>Aruba</option>
                <option value='BR'>Brazil</option>
                <option value='CH'>Chad</option>
                <option value='DN'>Denmark</option>
                <option value='EN'>England</option>
            </select>   
        </div>
        </br>
        </br>
        <div>
            <center><b>Siblings</b></center>
            <table  border='1' align='center' bgcolor='#C5E3BF'>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='name' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='age' size='3'/></td>                  
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='sGender' size='8'/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='name'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='age' size='3'/></td>                  
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='sGender' size='8'/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='name'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='age' size='3'/></td>                  
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='sGender'size='8'/></td>
                </tr>   
            </table>
        </div>
            </br>

        <div>
            <b><Center>Educations</center></b>
            <table border='1' bgcolor='#C5E3BF'>
                <center><tr>
                    <td>School Name</td>
                    <td>Year Graduated</td>
                    <td>Honor Received</td>
                </tr></center>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='sName'/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><select name='country'>
                <option value='2001'>2001</option>
                <option value='2002'>2002</option>
                <option value='2003'>2003</option>
                <option value='2004'>2004</option>
                <option value='2005'>2005</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type='text' value='' name='hnrReceived'/></td>
                </tr></center>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='sName'/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><select name='country'>
                <option value='2001'>2001</option>
                <option value='2002'>2002</option>
                <option value='2003'>2003</option>
                <option value='2004'>2004</option>
                <option value='2005'>2005</option>
                    </select></center>
                </td>
                <td><input type='text' value='' name='hnrReceived'/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' value='' name='sName'/></td>
                <td>
                    <center><select name='country'>
                <option value='2001'>2001</option>
                <option value='2002'>2002</option>
                <option value='2003'>2003</option>
                <option value='2004'>2004</option>
                <option value='2005'>2005</option>
                    </select></center>
                </td>
                <td><input type='text' value='' name='hnrReceived'/></td>
                </tr>   
            </table>        
        </div>

        <div>
        <label for='abtyrslf'><b>About Yourself:</b></label>
    </br>
        <textarea cols='50' rows='10' placeholder='Tell us something about yourself.'></textarea>
        </div>

        <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
        <input type='reset' value='Reset'/>

            </br>
            </br>
            </br>
        <div>
                <center><img src='gwaponess.jpg' id='pogi' height="190" width="190"/></center>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form> 
<hr/>
<center><h3><h3></center>
<hr/>
</body>
```

Comment: Some browsers do this automatically for you. Firefox certainly does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/49ucnq87/)

You can use **`:invalid` pseudo CSS** class

**CSS**

```
input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
input:valid {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
}
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)

> The :invalid CSS pseudo-class is applied automatically to 
>   elements whose contents fail to validate according to the input's type
>   setting. This allows you to easily have invalid fields adopt an
>   appearance that helps the user identify and correct errors.

Comment: Question, when I put that on my CSS code, upon opening of my html, the border automatically turns red. How do I solve that? The border should turn red only when I hit the submit button and there is an invalid data.

Comment: Please see the asnwer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27021959/3168859) @user4932301

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery validation for that...

```
  $('#forma').validate({
      rules : {
           fname: { required: true },
           lname: { required: true },
           eAdd: { requried: true },
           pass: { required: true }
           // and so on......
      }
   });
```

Just add reference for jquery lib and validation..