# Can't validate form in JS

Tags: javascript, forms

I can't validate the forms in this page, when i open it, it just says its a bad age despite everything i write

it should validate all the forms not just one
this is the JS

```
const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
const email = document.getElementById('mail');
const emailError = document.querySelector('#mail + span.error');
email.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
    if (email.validity.valid) {
        emailError.innerHTML = ''; 
        emailError.className = 'error'; 
    } else {
        showError();
    }
});

form.addEventListener('Introducir', function (event) {
    if(!email.validity.valid) {   
        showError();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

function showError() {
    if (email.validity.valueMissing) {
        emailError.textContent = 'La dirección introducida no es válida.';
    } else if (email.validity.typeMismatch) {
        emailError.textContent = 'Debes introducir una dirección valida.';
    } else if (email.validity.tooShort) {
        emailError.textContent = `El email debe ser como mínimo ${ email.minLength } caracteres de largo; tu has introducido ${ email.value.length }.`;
    }
    
    emailError.className = 'error';
}

if (edad.value < 18) {
    alert("Debes tener 18 o más")
} else {
    formulario.submit()
}
```

This is the HTML
i had to upload a screenshot because i can't add more code
[The HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXpfS.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You have not put your HTML code in your post. Can you add it?

Comment: Hi!, thanks, i can't add the HTML cause it say it's too much code srry, i'm going to try to write it anyway

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle?

Comment: Sure, https://jsfiddle.net/ejbrs0a8/

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems in the code you provided:

1. form fields are styled as invalid immediately, on page load
2. your `edad` form field is validated immediately, on page load

To solve problem #1, you should style your form fields as invalid when form has been submitted and/or form field has been validated, but not on page load.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27021959/9864539), which explains a solution to this problem.

---

To solve problem #2, you should wrap your `alert(...)` inside an event handler, for example:

```
const edad = document.getElementById("edad");
edad.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    if (this.value < 18) {
    alert("Debes tener 18 o más");
  } else {
    formulario.submit()
  }
});
```

Also note that an alert (expecially if it appears on user's input) is not the most user-friendly way to show an error. You should instead use an error message on the input field, like you've done for your `email` field:

```
const edad = document.getElementById("edad");
const edadError = document.querySelector('#edad + span.error');
edad.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    let value = parseInt(this.value);
  
    if (isNaN(value) || value < 18) {
    edadError.textContent = "Field is invalid.";
    edadError.className = "error";
  } else {
    edadError.textContent = "";
    edadError.classList.remove("error");
    formulario.submit()
  }
});
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqpxLd82/1/).