# applying style to a invalid form input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a red background in case an input is invalid. On form submit.

I already tried

```
input:invalid {
   background-color:red;
}
```

this works, but already shows up on page load, when ofcourse fields are empty.
I also tried this solution: [input:invalid css rule is applied on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021801/inputinvalid-css-rule-is-applied-on-page-load) but sadly that did not change a thing.

Comment: Did you try the code from [HomeSlice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75186659/82548) `input:not(:placeholder-shown):not(:focus):invalid {...}`? I ask because that seems to work in [a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7Lfd25mq/).

Answer (score 0):

html code

```
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
  <br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

css code

```
input:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

js

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input[required]");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (!inputs[i].checkValidity()) {
      inputs[i].classList.add("invalid");
    } else {
      inputs[i].classList.remove("invalid");
    }
  }
  if (form.checkValidity()) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: is it either the js way or the css way, that i need to use?